# itext 7 (java) add image on a new page to the end of an existing pdf document

Tags: java, merge, itext, itext7

i'm new to itext 7. I have a list of documents with different content that I want to merge into a single PDF. The content types are PDF, JPG & PNG.
My problem is that as soon as I merge a PDF and an image, the image is written over the already inserted content of the target PDF.
How do I get each image to be added to a new page of the target PDF?

This is my Code:

```
    byte[] mergeInhalt(List<Dokument> dokumentList) throws IOException {
      ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(byteOut);
      PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
      Document completeDocument = new Document(pdfDocument);

      for (Dokument dokument : dokumentList) {
        byte[] inhalt = dokument.getInhalt();
        if (Objects.nonNull(inhalt)) {
            switch (dokument.getFormat().name()) {
                case "PDF":
                    addPdf(pdfDocument, inhalt);
                    break;
                case "JPG":
                case "PNG":
                    ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create(inhalt);
                    Image image = new Image(data);
                    completeDocument.add(image);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    completeDocument.close();
    return byteOut.toByteArray();
}

private void addPdf(PdfDocument pdfDocument, byte[] inhalt) throws IOException {
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(inhalt));
    PdfDocument pdfDocumentToMerge = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
    pdfDocumentToMerge.copyPagesTo(1, pdfDocumentToMerge.getNumberOfPages(), pdfDocument);
}
```

Merging PDFs only works well, but everytime i merge a Image i get this:

[image]

The image with the pink one was placed over the text of the previous PDF

Comment: You add the image via the `document` but you add the pdf via the underlying `pdfDocument`. Thus, the `document` doesn't know about the added pdf and draws over it.

Comment: Is ist possible to add the Image to the pdfDocument? I searched a lot, but didnt find a solution.

Comment: Before adding any content to the `document`, try adding a `new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.LAST_PAGE)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code you add the image via the `Document completeDocument` but you add the pdf via the underlying `PdfDocument pdfDocument`. Thus, the `completeDocument` doesn't know about the added pdf, continues on its current page, and draws over the imported pages.

To make sure each image is added on a new page after the currently last one, you have to tell `completeDocument` to move its current page:

```
case "JPG":
case "PNG":
    ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create(inhalt);
    Image image = new Image(data);
    completeDocument.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.LAST_PAGE));
    completeDocument.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
    completeDocument.add(image);
    break;
```

For an example compare the tests [testMergeLikeAndreasHuber](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/merge/CopyPdfsAndImages.java#L44) and [testMergeLikeAndreasHuberImproved](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/merge/CopyPdfsAndImages.java#L87) in [CopyPdfsAndImages](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/merge/CopyPdfsAndImages.java) and their outputs.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped for me :-)